# PubNub Presence Repeating 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, pubnub

I'm trying to use PubNub presence in my app and I'm getting a repeating forbidden error.  I do have the permissions enabled in the PubNub Admin Portal.

Here is my subscription code:

```
var initSettings: pubnub.IInitSettings = {
    publish_key: "myPubKey",
    subscribe_key: "mySubKey",
    uuid: "myUUID",
    auth_key: "myAuthKey"
};

this.pubnub = PUBNUB(initSettings);
console.log(this.pubnub);

var subscribeSettings: pubnub.ISubscribeSettings = {
    channel: "chat",
    presence: this.userConnected,
    message: this.processMessage
};

this.pubnub.subscribe(subscribeSettings);
```

This is my `userConnected` callback:

```
userConnected = (m: any) => {
    var hereNowSettings: pubnub.IHereNowSettings = {
        channel: this.channelString,
        callback: (message: any) => {
            this.channelCount++;
        }

    };

    this.pubnub.here_now(hereNowSettings);
};
```

I get a repeating error that says

> `pubnub-3.7.14.js:2644 GET http://ps17.pubnub.com/subscribe/mySubKey/chat%2Cchat-pnpres/0/0?uuid=myUUID&pnsdk=PubNub-JS-Web%2F3.7.14 403 (Forbidden)`

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Can anyone explain this?

## **UPDATE:**

I added a secret key and grant to my pubnub config:

```
createPubNubConnections() {
    let initSettings: pubnub.IInitSettings = {
        publish_key: publishKey,
        subscribe_key: subscribeKey,
        uuid: uuid,
        auth_key: authKey,
        secret_key: secretKey
    };

    this.pubnub = PUBNUB(initSettings);
    console.log(this.pubnub);

    let subscribeSettings: pubnub.ISubscribeSettings = {
        channel: "chat",
        presence: this.userConnected,
        message: this.processMessage
    };

    this.pubnub.subscribe(subscribeSettings);

    let grantSettings: pubnub.IGrantSettings = {
        read: true,
        callback: (message: any) => { console.log(message); }
    };

    this.pubnub.grant(grantSettings);
}
```

However, now I'm getting an error that says

> Missing Secret Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PubNub Access Manager & Granting Permissions

If you have Access Manager enabled then your server must grant permission to `read` on the channel and the presence channel if you are going to subscribe (with presence) on that channel.

You said:

> permissions enabled in the PubNub Admin Portal

... but you do not enable (grant) permissions in the Admin Portal, you grant permission in code using the secret key.

See the following links for how to use Access Manager to grant permissions:

- [PubNub Access Manager Getting Started Tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/tutorials/pubnub-access-manager)
- [PubNub JavaScript SDK Access Manager Tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security)

**TL;DR** (from the links above)
You have to `grant` the *read* permission on both the *channel* and its *-pnpres* channel. So if you grant read to "*chat*" then you need to grant read to "*chat-pnpres*", if you want to subscribe to presence events on that channel. It also gives you `get/setState`, `herenow` and `wherenow` permissions on the channel (*chat*), too.

---

### UPDATE for latest versions of PubNub SDKs

By the way, with current PubNub SDKs, the `secret-key` gives you all permissions on all channels and channel groups. So do NOT include an *auth-key* when you `init` PubNub with a *secret-key* because the *auth-key* will override the *secret-key* with respect to all PubNub requests other than `grant` by your server.

#### [Secret Key - All Permissions](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pam-security#pubnub_access_manager_consumer-side_configuration)

> Anyone with the secretKey can grant and revoke permissions to your app. Never let your secretKey be discovered, and to only exchange it / deliver it securely. Only use the secretKey on secure server-side platforms.

Comment: I updated my question with the new code.  Is there any way you could help me with this problem? As far as I can tell I'm using it correctly.

Comment: Never mind I figured everything out.  Thank you for your answer it was very helpful.

Comment: make sure you only use the secret key in you secure server, never in your client side apps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've granted read permission on the presence channel also.

E.g. if the channel is `my_channel`, grant read permission to the `my_channel-pnpres` presence channel also.

More info available [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/presence#receiving_presence_join_leave)